# MCMC: potential causes of poor mixing within small parameter space

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, markov-process, convergence, hierarchical-bayesian

I am currently running into a peculiar issue where after running a Bayesian state-space model, independent MCMC chains all end up within a small parameter space (say within +/-.01 region), but there is poor mixing between chains. Chains for slope parameters on standardized variables are initiated using a random number of mean zero and sd=1. To me, this indicates that the MCMC sampler is finding the correct parameter space, but I do not understand why the chains themselves remain separated. The plot below is an example, although this is happening for all parameters. The plot shows 20k iterations after a 100k burn-in phase. Increasing the number of iterations does not solve the problem. I wish to know if this points to any general issues with MCMC sampling before looking towards the details of my actual model. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Is the model that you are sampling from a unimodal one?

Comment: We would really need to know more about your model to do anything but guess.   It could be, for example, that you have several parameters that are highly correlated, but you aren't sampling them as a block or reparameterizing the model to make them more independent; in situations like that, in my experience, you can have a great deal of difficulty moving the block of parameters away from their current location.

Comment: It can happen for multiple reasons. Which MCMC algorithm are you using? There are multiple versions - basic MCMC, DRAMS, and DREAMS etc? How do you choose your starting point for the chains? As others have asked, what is your model - is it uni-modal or multi-modal? Smallness of parameter space is a relative term, it depends on the nature (peakedness) of your likelihood function. If the current peaks are too large compared to other regions in the parameter space, then you chains are likely to be stuck in a very small region as you see in your example.